# cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

My input data is under the form:

```
    gold,Program,MethodType,CallersT,CallersN,CallersU,CallersCallersT,CallersCallersN,CallersCallersU,CalleesT,CalleesN,CalleesU,CalleesCalleesT,CalleesCalleesN,CalleesCalleesU,CompleteCallersCallees,classGold
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,Medium,High,-1,High,0,Trace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,Medium,High,-1,High,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,Low,High,Medium,-1,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,0,NoTrace,
T,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,Low,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,Low,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,0,NoTrace,
....
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,NoTrace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,Low,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,Trace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,NoTrace,
```

I am reading my data and I am trying to concatenate two data sets that are subsets of the original data set, here is the code I am using:

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
SeparateProjectLearning=False
CompleteCallersCallees=False
PartialTrainingSetCompleteCallersCallees=True
def main():
    X_train={}
    X_test={}
    y_train={}
    y_test={}
    dataset = pd.read_csv( 'InputData.txt', sep= ',', index_col=False) 
    #convert T into 1 and N into 0
    dataset['gold'] = dataset['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['Program'] = dataset['Program'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['classGold'] = dataset['classGold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes
    
    dataset['CallersT'] = dataset['CallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersN'] = dataset['CallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersU'] = dataset['CallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersT'] = dataset['CallersCallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersN'] = dataset['CallersCallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersU'] = dataset['CallersCallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes 
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    row_count, column_count = dataset.shape
    Xcol = dataset.iloc[:, 1:column_count]
        
              
    
    
    CompleteSet=dataset.loc[dataset['CompleteCallersCallees'] == 1]
    CompleteSet_X = CompleteSet.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
    CompleteSet_Y = CompleteSet.iloc[:, 0].values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(CompleteSet_X, CompleteSet_Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
    TestSet=dataset.loc[dataset['CompleteCallersCallees'] == 0]
    X_test1=TestSet.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
    X_test=pd.concat(X_test1,X_test)
```

I want to build my own test set and training set by using concatenation and I am trying to concatenate `X_test1` and `X_test` in the code above. However, the problem is that I am getting an error for the last line of code  `X_test=pd.concat(X_test1,X_test)` and the error says `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding `.values` to the end of your filters in the following lines:

```py
CompleteSet_X = CompleteSet.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
CompleteSet_Y = CompleteSet.iloc[:, 0].values
X_test1=TestSet.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
```

You are extracting the underlying Numpy `ndarray` from the Pandas `Series`/`DataFrame` the prior code extracts, just remove `.values` at the end and you can use `concat` directly with the `Series` or `DataFrame`.